# How to create a Custom Xcode preprocessor macro

Tags: ios, xcode, preprocessor

I'm trying to create a preprocessor macro to simplify a bit of code that I'm continually using.  The code just creates a dictionary and then posts a notification.  Like so:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"This is a test"
                                                 forKey:@"debugMessage"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FLRDebugViewLog"
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:dict];
```

I'd love to create a macro so that I could just type:

```
MBDebug(@"This is a test",self);
```

i.e. just passing in the message and object I want to post.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Any reason why you want a macro over a regular C function?

Comment: I hadn't even considered a c function.  I guess the only reason I was thinking macro was because I'm just expanding text, essentially, so a compile time macro seemed like it'd be most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. :)

```
#define MBDebug(m,s) NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:m forKey:@"debugMessage"]; [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FLRDebugViewLog" object:s userInfo:dict];
```

Comment: Wow, I guess I should have figured that out myself.  Thanks!